# What is the best way to avoid missincluding same files?

Tags: c++, dll, include

Given the file tree:

```
DLL1
└───source
    ├───File1.h
    └───SameHeader.h
DLL2
└───source
    ├───File2.h
    └───SameHeader.h
```

File1 includes SameHeader.h, which is fine.
File2 includes File1 which won't compile, because the #include "SameHeader.h" now  points to the DLL2/source/SameHeader.h. Is there a way to ensure File1 uses the file which in the same dll?

Comment: Sure: use different names for both header files. Problem solved.

Comment: It seems a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: @rustyx -- there's no such requirement, and different compilers do it differently. For some, `#include "SameHeader.h"` looks first in the directory of the **source file** being compiled; for others, it looks first in the directory of the **current file**, which, as here, could be "File1.h" or "File2.h". But neither of those is required; formally, the places to search are implementation defined.

Comment: @Adrian -- although it's not 100% clear, it looks to me like the two headers named "SameHeader.h" aren't the same, just have the same name. If they're identical the problem described in the question doesn't happen.

Comment: @Adrian -- your answer has only one file named "SameHeader.h".

Comment: @Adrian -- you can't have it both ways. "... I have assumed ... same name, two different files" is not the same as "only one file".

Comment: @Pere Becker OK, to clarify: My assumption of two different files was made concerning the OP's situation; my assertion of "one file, no ambiguity" relates to my proffered answer. Got it?

Comment: @Adrian -- got it. Keep on handwaving.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sure - you can put the file `SameHeader.h` in a separate folder (not the same as the source files) and then specify that folder in your list of include paths to search (in the project options, or in the compiler command switches).

You will, of course, need to delete the file `SameHeader.h` from each of the source project directories, or that will be used in preference to the one in the separate folder.

So, using your "file tree" diagram, I would suggest this:

```
DLL1
└───source
├───File1.h
DLL2
└───source
├───File2.h
Include
└───SameHeader.h
```

You could then add `../Include` to your compiler's include file search path. How to do this depends on your compiler and/or environment, but it will be something along the lines of a `/I"..\_Include"` switch in MSVC or (probably) `-I"../_Include"` with clang. This is what I do in multi-project solutions, for all header files that will be used by more than one project.

However, if you actually need two (different) `SameHeader.h` files, then you should perhaps specify the full path name (or, at least, a qualified path) in the `#include "SameHeader.h"` line in File1 - something like: `#include "../../DLL1/source/SameHeader.h"` (depending on the exact layout of your files & folders).

Comment: If the two "SameHeader.h" files are identical in content the problem cited in the question doesn't occur. So they must be different, and you can't just copy one of them and delete the other.

Comment: The contents are different, I don't copy files. I think there's no way to achive what I want, unless if I include it with the full path (which one I wanted to avoid). I appreciate your time trying to solve my problem.

Comment: @user12067300 Ah! Sorry, my latest edit was posted just before your comment! I'll get back to it. But maybe you should consider splitting the content of each `SameHeader.h` so that the bits that need to be **common** to both DLLs are in a separate header, and the bits that are **specific** to each are in their own, respective header.